# iOS PhoneGap ChildBrowser "data argument not used by format string" warnings with XCode 4.4

Tags: ios5, cordova, childbrowser

I've updated XCode to v4.4 and started getting warnings in the PhoneGap (Cordova 1.9.0) ChildBrowser plug-in that never showed up with v4.3. (Nothing else in my code changed.) When I saw these warnings, I pulled the latest version of the ChildBrowser plugin and that didn't make the warnings go away, either.

Anyway... in ChildBrowserCommand.m:

```
-(void) onClose
{
    NSString* jsCallback = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose();",@""];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallback];
}

-(void) onOpenInSafari
{
    NSString* jsCallback = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.plugins.childBrowser.onOpenExternal();",@""];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallback];
}
```

Each of these give a "Data argument not used by format string" warning. This makes sense since  there's no place for the `@""` to be placed into the format string even if it had a value.

I'm no Objective-C expert but realize I can get rid of the warning by deleting the `,@""` in the call.

Just posting in case anyone can explain why this started showing up after updating to XCode 4.4 and whether/how this should be flagged as an issue with the iOS PhoneGap ChildBrowser plugin on GitHub.

Comment: You should write your solution as a proper answer below, then when able to, accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and i have to admit I did not notice your answer so:
I have no idea why this fix it and will be happy to know but this is the fix.
To fix this use the following code:

```
-(void) onClose
{
    NSString* jsCallback = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose();"];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallback];
}

-(void) onOpenInSafari
{
    NSString* jsCallback = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.plugins.childBrowser.onOpenExternal();"];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallback];
}
```